# How to schedule SMS using Twilio w/o using Celery?

Tags: django, python-3.x, twilio

I want to schedule SMS using Twilio in Python. After reading some articles I came to know about Celery.
But I opted not to use celery and go with Python Threading module. Threading module works perfectly when using some dummy function, but when calling

```
        client.api.account.messages.create(
            to="+91xxxxxxxxx3",
            from_=settings.TWILIO_CALLER_ID,
            body=message)
```

it sends the SMS at the same time.

Here is my code

```
from threading import Timer 
from django.conf import settings
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = settings.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID
auth_token = settings.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
message = to_do
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
run_at = user_given_time() #this function extracts the user given time from database. it works perfectly fine.

# find current DateTime
now = DT.now()
now = DT.strptime(str(now), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
now = now.replace(microsecond=0)

delay = (run_at - now).total_seconds()
Timer(delay, client.api.account.messages.create(
                                               to="+91xxxxxxxxx3",                                                          
                                      from_=settings.TWILIO_CALLER_ID,
                                      body=to_do)).start()
```

So the problem is that Twilio sends SMS at the same time, but I want it to send after given delay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function *before* starting your Timer, and then passing your Timer thread the return value. You need to pass Timer the function `client.api.account.messages.create` and the kwargs to pass it as separate arguments so the thread can call the function itself when the time comes:

```
Timer(delay, client.api.account.messages.create, 
      kwargs={'to': "+91xxxxxxxxx3",
              'from_': settings.TWILIO_CALLER_ID,
              'body'=to_do)).start()
```

See the [documentation for Timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) and notice that it takes `args` and `kwargs` parameters to pass to the provided function.

Answer (score 0):

The `Timer` shouldn't be used with web service, here's the reason:

1. Web requests are served using multiple threads.
2. You need to wait for the timer thread to execute so it will become blocking otherwise, timer thread won't be executed.

Hence I would recommend, use some any queue to do such things.